# Modification needed for base64

Tags: php, base64

Problem with base64

```
$data = 'my data';
echo $encryptedData = base64_encode($data);
```

// Output :
bXkgZGF0YQ==

I added some more characters to the token

```
$encryptedData = $encryptedData . 'sdfsdfasdfsd';
echo $data = base64_decode($encryptedData);
```

// Output :
my data~Ç_jÇ_±

Now i got actual data + junk data. i dont want **any of the data** or **only the data** if there is any change in the token. is there any method to implement this ?

Comment: Are you trying to protect against *deliberate* tampering, or accidental data loss? Your variable names concern me, by the way - you know that base64 is in no way *encryption*, right? It doesn't make the contents secret at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm guessing OP wants to detect only authoritative changes to `$data`, rather than deducing it from the given base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure changes to the base64 encoded string can only be made by changing the `$data`, you will need to add a verification token.

An easy way to add such verification is by using a keyed hash whereby the key is secret:

```
$data = 'this product sells for 5 dollars';
$enc = base64_encode($data);
$token = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $enc, 'your secret key here', true));

$my_token = $token . ':' . $enc;
```

Output:

```
ZMkqZIa6UazMhbYDiPqjdS1NmU1ulh+Gi2tgWHRKKpQ=:dGhpcyBwcm9kdWN0IHNlbGxzIGZvciA1IGRvbGxhcnM=
```

When you receive such token, you first split on `:` and then use the first part (keyed hash) to verify the contents of the second part (data). Only if it matches, you can be (relatively) sure that the data has not been tampered with.

Answer (score 2):

you should add token while encoding instead decoding

```
$data = 'my data'.'sdfsdfasdfsd';
$encryptedData = base64_encode($data);
```

than

```
echo $data = base64_decode($encryptedData);
```

and to remove  the token

```
$trimmed = rtrim($data, "sdfsdfasdfsd");
echo $trimmed;
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/urrcSdvy)

and as Jon Skeet said  base64 is in no way encryption .It doesn't make the contents secret at all